# Oracle SQL : Getting one result set for multiple select queries on the same table

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my first post on stackoverflow so please be patient. Assume I have an employee table with roles a,b,c,d, etc. I needed the result of the first 5 employees with role A, the first 5 employees with role B and the first 5 employees with role C. Please note that I need all columns of the table in my result set. Any help will be much appreciated.

---

### SAMPLE DATA

```
Name---Dept---Role  
abc1---HR---A  
abc2---HR---B  
abc3---HR---C  
abc4---HR---D  
abc5---HR---A  
abc6---HR---B  
abc7---HR---C  
abc8---DEV---D  
abc9---DEV---A  
abc10---DEV---B  
abc11---DEV---C  
abc12---DEV---D  
abc13---DEV---A  
abc14---DEV---B  
abc15---DEV---C  
abc16---Test---D  
abc17---Test---A  
abc18---Test---B  
abc19---Test---C  
abc20---Test---D  
abc21---Test---A  
abc22---Test---B  
abc23---Test---C  
abc24---Test---D  
abc25---Test---A  
abc26---Test---B
```

---

### REQUIRED OUTPUT

```
Name---Dept---Role  
abc1---HR---A  
abc5---HR---A  
abc9---DEV---A  
abc13---DEV---A  
abc17---Test---A  
abc2---HR---B  
abc6---HR---B  
abc10---DEV---B  
abc14---DEV---B  
abc18---Test---B  
abc3---HR---C  
abc7---HR---C  
abc11---DEV---C  
abc15---DEV---C  
abc19---Test---C
```

Thanks,
Sud

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far and required output...!! and welcome to SO : please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: please add more details, sample data, examples

Comment: "the first 5 employees with role A"? What does "the first" mean exactly here? Just five arbitrarily picked? Or the first five in alphabetic order? Or something else?

Comment: Is this homework? Do you need a hint what to look for? Have you tried anything yourself? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Alphabetic will do fine

Comment: This isn't homework. I work in an organisation and am trying to implement some logic in my automation code.

Comment: I've posted an answer. Next time you should at least show what you've tried yourself. We'll be more ready to help then.

Answer (score 1):

You want to rank records (first/best five per role). Such is done with analytic functions such as `RANK`, `DENSE_RANK` and `ROW_NUMBER`.

```
select name, dept, role
from
(
  select name, dept, role, row_number() over (partition by role order by name) as rn
  from employees
  where role in ('A', 'B', 'C')
)
where rn <= 5
order by role, name;
```

Comment: Thank for the answer, Thorsten. I had tried a lot of queries and all of them contained sensitive content. That meant changing everything to the format used in my example. I will make it a point next time, tho.